# Please I don't know how to solve this question (due to the boundaries)

Tags: functions

[I don't know how to solve this when a boundary is given.
Please highlight the significance of the boundary in your solutions.   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XGtP.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: can't understand your handwriting

Comment: Can you fill us in on your background? For example do you know calculus or is this from an algebra class?

Comment: I'm a first year computer science student. This is from algebra, but I know calculus too.

Comment: I understand perfectly well how to solve such questions without intervals;  but know not how to solve them with intervals.

Comment: Try using latex / mathjax to let us better understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking for the range of $\dfrac {1+x}{1-x}$ when $x>1$.

In that case $x-1>0$, and, for all real $x$,  $x+1>x-1$, so $\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}>1$.

Now multiply that last inequality by $-1$,

and don't forget to reverse the inequality sign when doing that.

Comment: Thanks sir J. W. Tanner . But I have some doubts; how did you have the inequality x + 1 > x - 1 ?  Is it obvious as per the question or it's obtained through some reasoning?   And why multiply the last inequality by -1 ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: take $1>-1$  and add $x$ to both sides to get $x+1>x-1$; multiply by $-1$ to get from $\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$ to $\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$

Comment: Wow, I get it now!! Thanks a ton. (Exams tomorrow )

Comment: Good luck, and thank you for the "acceptance"